# Not able to pull or push when a network share path is configured as remote repository in Git

Tags: git, repository

Problem – When I try to configure network file share as remote repository, I was unable to push and pull the changes to and from remote and local repositories. I am only managed to clone the repository from remote to local. Whenever I does push or pull, it shows the following error message:

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

My remote repository address looks like this – `\\192.xxx.x.50\GitRemote\`

Can you please help to resolve this issue? Please let me know if I can provide more information.

Note: When I have remote repository in the same machine (local file system) then it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try another syntax for the shared folder url

```
git remote set-url origin //192.xxx.x.50/GitRemote
or
git remote set-url origin \\192.xxx.x.50\GitRemote
```

(as seen in "[Git pull from another users working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4614016/6309)")

Comment: Hi, I tried this too (//192.xxx.x.50/GitRemote). But it didn't work. I was able to clone but not the push or pull. FYI - I am an admin on that network share path machine too. Not sure if i am missing something here.

Comment: @user ok, what error message do you see when you try to push?