# View a file in a different Git branch without changing branches

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch

Is it possible to open a file in a git branch without checking out that branch? How?

Essentially I want to be able to open a file in my [github pages](http://pages.github.com/) branch without switching branches all the time. I don't want to modify it, just want to view it.

Comment: All the answers missed the fact you need to specify the full path of the file with `git show`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610208/how-to-retrieve-a-single-file-from-specific-revision-in-git/610315#610315 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364147/how-to-get-just-one-file-from-another-branch/2364223#2364223

Comment: These days, you can use `git show a1b35:./file.txt` to use relative paths.

Comment: @VonC - thank goodness for branch-aware tab completion :)

Comment: more interesting could be showing differences `git diff <other_branch> <path>`

Comment: The relative file example above with "a1b35", that is the branch name -- so of course put your own branch name there.

Answer (score 1209, accepted):

This should work:

```
git show branch:file
```

Where *branch* can be any ref (branch, tag, HEAD, ...) and *file* is the full path of the file. To export it you could use

```
git show branch:file > exported_file
```

You should also look at [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc)'s answers to some related questions:

- [How to retrieve a single file from specific revision in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610208/how-to-retrieve-a-single-file-from-specific-revision-in-git/610315#610315)
- [How to get just one file from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364147/how-to-get-just-one-file-from-another-branch/2364223#2364223)

UPDATE 2015-01-19:

Nowadays you can use relative paths with `git show a1b35:./file.txt`.

Comment: And you can pop the file open in vim as well: `git show branch:file | vim -` (Notice the "|" pipe, and the trailing dash after the vim command: `vim -`

Comment: @GregBurghardt: That's cool. It would be cooler if I can somehow give vim a hint about how to highlight the content

Comment: I think if you do `vim -c "set syntax on" -` that should turn syntax highlighting on. Haven't tried it yet.

Comment: @GregBurghardt what works for me is something similar to `vim -c "set syntax=html" -`

Comment: @rparree vim guesses the correct syntax from the file suffix. You can avoid this by adding a vim modline as a comment to your files. That way you can also set more file-specific settings, i.e. indentation etc.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic

Comment: After piping into vim just press the colon key and type `set syntax=python` or whatever :)

Comment: This ONLY shows local branches, it does NOT show all branches on server

Comment: @FullDecent, I was able to use ```origin/my_remote_branch``` fine with this.  Or do you mean the actual server version? If you want that, you just need to ```git fetch``` first.

Comment: if you are in Vim, you can do `%!git show <yourbranchname>:%`  that will open the git show result in a buffer,

Answer (score 91):

```
git show somebranch:path/to/your/file
```

you can also do multiple files and have them concatenated:

```
git show branchA~10:fileA branchB^^:fileB
```

You do not have to provide the full path to the file, relative paths are acceptable e.g.:

```
git show branchA~10:../src/hello.c
```

If you want to get the file in the local directory (revert just one file) you can checkout:

```
git checkout somebranch -- path/to/file
```

Comment: For Windows users: This is one of the few places where git bash for Windows doesn't know to normalise case and path separators. i.e. You must match the case exactly and use `/`  instead of `\ ` - even though cmd's completion will try to tell you the opposite.

Answer (score 46):

A simple, newbie friendly way for looking into a file: 
`git gui browser <branch>` which lets you explore the contents of any file.

It's also there in the File menu of `git gui`. Most other -more advanced- GUI wrappers (Qgit, Egit, etc..) offer browsing/opening files as well.

Comment: This command results "git: 'gui' is not a git command.  See 'git --help'.  I'm a newbie; what's going on?

Comment: It actually works (to my surprise), see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui - I use git version 2.5.2.windows.1

Comment: This answer was very helpful! Thanks. Should mention that im using git bash on windows.

Comment: Is it possible to use ranger as git gui?

Comment: @ScottBiggs you are not a newbie, you are using a nonstandard setup.

Comment: A blank window pops up for me.

Comment: Only drawback is, you have to close the git gui browser (file viewer) in order to use the command line (git bash) again. I suspect that opening a new (git bash) window, would get around this restriction.

Comment: @Blubber  you need to do it from the root directory, where the main .git is present

Comment: Just a note that `git gui` command seems not be installed with MacOS Monterey. Use `brew install git-gui` to add it.

Answer (score 24):

If you're using Emacs, you can type `C-x v ~` or `M-x vc-revision-other-window` to see a different revision of the file you're currently editing (tags, branches and hashes all work).

Comment: Is there a way to get this in Vim? (I'm open to plug-ins.)

Comment: timeless advice !

Comment: @NHDaly vim-fugitive can do it: `:Git show branch:path/file` will open it in a new window.

Answer (score 13):

Add the following to your `~/.gitconfig` file

```
[alias]
  cat = "!git show \"$1:$2\" #"
```

And then try this

```
git cat BRANCHNAME FILEPATH
```

Personally I prefer separate parameters without a colon. Why? This choice mirrors the parameters of the `checkout` command, which I tend to use rather frequently and I find it thus much easier to remember than the bizarro colon-separated parameter of the `show` command.

Comment: **Bash completions** works with git aliases immediately after `.git/config` was saved, e.g. save config and try `git cat ma[tab-tab] docke[tab-tab]`. Thx, @akuhn