# git look at code in other branch without switching

Tags: git, emacs

Often, when doing refactoring work in branch "Y" using `git`, I think to myself -- How was this done in branch "X"?  My local repo's in no place for a checkin -- and `stash`ing so that I can switch branches, inspect the file in the other branch and then switch back (trying not to forget to `stash pop`) in the process seems way too hacky.  Is there a way to get a handle on the file in another branch so that I can display it next to the version in my current branch?

My editor is `emacs` if that makes any difference.  The ideal solution would give me a separate emacs buffer for the file in branch "X" -- But I realize that might be asking too much.  Even something as simple as a hypothetical `git cat myfile otherbranch` would be helpful.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856416/in-git-view-a-file-in-a-different-branch-without-changing-branches

Comment: @mohit6up -- exactly what I wanted.  Thanks.  I voted to close this as a duplicate -- you should too.  I thought about just deleting it, but I thought someone else might find this easier on a google search.

Comment: @ALL -- Please vote to close this as recommended [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157389/is-there-any-value-to-not-deleting-my-own-duplicate-question)

Comment: good idea. I'm afraid it'll have to be others as I don't think I have the privilege.

Comment: There may be some way to do this via `git cat-file` ... but I don't really understand the `man` page.

Comment: I added [an Emacs-specific answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14886215/113848) to that other question.