# View two different files on two different branches in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, git, xcode5, version-editor

How is it possible to view two different files on two different git branches in Xcode? I have renamed one of my class and also added new logic to it. And now I would like to see together the two file in the left and right panel. Meantime I created and checked out a new branch and committed changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this isn't possible, but there are ways of getting the file's contents using  the `git` command line.  See the following SO questions:

- [View a file in a different Git branch without changing branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856416/view-a-file-in-a-different-git-branch-without-changing-branches).
- [How to get just one file from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364147/how-to-get-just-one-file-from-another-branch/2364223#2364223).

Comment: Also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099742/how-can-i-compare-files-from-two-different-branches

Answer (score 0):

In case is not just a file, copy the project folder and switch the branch in one of the copies. Then, open the two copies in two different windows on xcode and you will have the whole set of features of the editor for the two branches.