# How to get list of files in another branch without checkout

Tags: git, git-show

I want to list the files present in another branch without doing a checkout, and according to [View a file in a different Git branch without changing branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7856416/5916915), this command is sufficient:

```
git show mybranch:mydir
```

Unfortunately, the output is not ideal because of the completely unnecessary `tree mybranch:mydir`:

```
tree mybranch:mydir

.gitignore
Makefile
README
```

How can I list the files in another branch without getting any extra information (e.g. `tree mybranch:mydir`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would then be

```
git -p ls-tree -r --name-only mybranch:mydir
```

Drop `-p` if you do not need the pager. Drop `-r` if you do not want to descend into directories recursively.

Comment: Which Git version is this? I am using Git 2.17.1. I get no output (with exit code 0) when I run this.

Comment: I have 2.23.0 here. But that should not make a difference; the command hasn't changed since aeons. Show your exact command.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. This command must be run from the root of the repository.