# How do I open a file from another Git branch in Emacs?

Tags: bash, git, emacs

Working in `BranchA`, I frequently need to refer to a file in `BranchB`.  The `git show BranchB:path/to/file` command will dump the contents of `file` to the terminal, but that's hard to read and navigate.  I'd like to have `BranchB:path/to/file` open in an Emacs window.

The top comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7856446/6673905) indicates that I can do this with vim by `git show branch:file | vim -`.  If I try this with Emacs,

```
git show BranchB:path/to/file | emacs -
```

an empty Emacs buffer opens with a message "Unknown option '-'" in the minibuffer.

I know that I can send the output of `git show` to a file and then open that file in Emacs, but I'm looking for a more streamlined workflow that I expect exists.

How can I open a file from another Git branch directly in Emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a cross-site duplicate of superuser's [How to make Emacs read buffer from stdin on start?](https://superuser.com/a/821624/132797). The answer there works here:

```
emacs --insert <(git show BranchB:path/to/file)
```

Comment: I wouldn't have thought to search for that phrasing on my own, but this is correct.  For this method, Emacs does not apply the syntax color-coding for a recognized file type, but I can work on that separately.  Thanks!