# Not able to analyze properties of text in git bash

Tags: git-bash, cat

I have committed a few test text from my vim editor to a sample main branch.

When I use `$cat (commit)` to view various versions across branches, my editor simply clears as if I typed `$clear`.

Comment: Are you typing the literal command `cat; (commit)`? If so, what does your `commit` command do? Note that neither `cat` nor `commit` is a *Git* command. Git-bash has nothing to do with Git itself, it's just a port of Bash to Windows so that Windows users can use Git (which needs a POSIX-style shell, and bash provides one). If you are typing `(commit)`, note that to bash, this means run the `commit` command in a sub-shell; if that clears your screen, that would do the job.

Comment: (Note further that `cat (commit)` just produces a syntax error, so I'm sure that's not what you're actually typing. See [mre] - providing a reproducible example helps others to help you!)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`git show`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7856448/6309) to see the content of a file in a different branch

```
git show somebranch:path/to/your/file
```

Or you can define a [`git cat` alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54819889/6309)

```
[alias]
  cat = "!git show \"$1:$2\" #"
```

Which means you can type `git cat somebranch path/to/your/file`.