# git - checkout single file under bare repository

Tags: git, sh, githooks

On the server I have bare repository which is origin for development process and to simplify deployment to QA environment.

So in `post-receive` it simply does

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/dev git checkout -f
```

But as product gets more complicated there are some other things should be happening. So now it is handled by `deploy.sh` script which is also tracked by repository. So what I want to do is to be able instead of checking out whole repository is to checkout only `deploy.sh` and run it. I thought something like that would work:

```
SOURCE_PATH="/home/dev"
GIT_WORK_TREE=$SOURCE_PATH git checkout deploy.sh
$SOURCE_PATH"/deploy.sh"
```

But it does not work giving error:

```
error: pathspec 'deploy.sh' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is it just impossible to do this way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As I explain in "[checkout only one file from git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2467629/6309)", you cannot checkout just one file without cloning or fetching first.

But you [`git show` that file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610208/how-to-retrieve-a-single-file-from-specific-revision-in-git), which means you can dump its content into a `/another/path./deploy.sh` file, and execute that file.

```
git-show HEAD:full/repo/path/to/deploy.sh > /another/path./deploy.sh
/another/path./deploy.sh
```

Since you execute that from a post-receive hook, the [`git-show`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) will show the latest version of the `deploy.sh` file.

---

The other alternative would be try

```
 GIT_WORK_TREE=$SOURCE_PATH git checkout -- path/to/deploy.sh
```

And checkout only that file, directly in your working tree.

The '`--`' help the git command to understand it is a file, not another parameter like a tag or a named branch.

From the [OP AlexKey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1297136/alexkey)'s test, it requires that the working tree has been checked out (fully) at least once.

Comment: Maybe that's right, but it is a bit weird. So in bare repository we actually can checkout by `simulating` appended work tree, but that will allow us checkout whole tree only. Which sounds for me not really `thought through` implementation. Right now (for time saving purpose) i do checkout all tree twice, first in hook and then in deployment script. Meanwhile i will look for a proper solution and if will find nothing then only thing i will have to do is to use this `trick`.

Comment: @AlexKey did you try to checkout just `deploy.sh` with the `--`? I believe this is what you wanted to do.

Comment: Haven't tried that solution. In that case what exactly would path/to/deploy.sh be? For example if in my repo this script is at `./deploy.sh` the command will look like `GIT_WORK_TREE=$SOURCE_PATH git checkout -- deploy.sh`?

Comment: Seems that this works only if the whole tree was already checked out at least once. Otherwise it gives same error.

Comment: @AlexKey ok, back to the `git show` then: you would not need to checkout the tree twice that way, just to get `deploy.sh`.

Comment: There i meant that once it can be checked out manually. But then I can remove resulting tree and on next push and later on it will checkout only that file with no problem. I am not much aware of how this works in git, but assume that on first checkout it builds index of files that were checked out or something like that and then uses it to find file if you try to check it out. Still will try experiment with it. However, now on my server `--` solution works fine. I only had to do `git checkout -f` first time.

Comment: @AlexKey not sure what you mean: the idea (with `git show`) is to dump the content of one file (outside of any git repo), and then that file does all the checkout you need.

Comment: Yes, i got that. But out of chase for perfection i would like to find more beautiful solution :) I definitely accept that option with `git-show`, thus i marked this answer as accepted, but if we talk about alternative `--` option, which is also present in your answer, then i would like to be more precise and specify how it works. Otherwise someone who will read this answer later may run into the same issue as me when it still produces the error.

Comment: @AlexKey so you are saying that, if the working tree hasn't been checked out at least once, the `git checkout` will fail, right?

Comment: Exactly. I have seen your edit and immediately tried it on test repo on my local system and it worked because i already used there `GIT_WORK_TREE=/path git checkout -f`. And then i implemented this on our QA server, tested and it produced error, then i did same `git checkout -f` on QA server and after that `--` works as a charm.

Comment: @AlexKey and now that a full checkout has been done once, could we say the next checkout of that one file will always work? I have edited the answer to make that step more apparent.

Comment: exactly like that. I have no idea why is it happening this way, but it does. I've tried on git v1.5 and on v1.7. Same outcome on both versions.

Comment: Nice, but in the first method (e.g. inside a hook) how to preserve file permissions?

Comment: @AkiRoss which kind of permissions do you want to preserve? Git only records two (644 755: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26603078/6309). It is best in the hook to configure it in order for a file to be checked out with the expected permission (like with umask)

Comment: @VonC Only the executable flag: I'm creating a server hook that uses `git show` to get a file, but the executable permission is lost. I would like to keep it.

Comment: @AkiRoss if need be, a simple chmod in the hook would ensure that this file regain the expected protection.

Comment: The problem is that some files are +x, others -x.

Comment: @AkiRoss what is the value of git config core.fileMode? (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config). Git depends on the system to restore the proper protection, and it depends on the specifics of the environment. See for instance http://superuser.com/q/512393/141 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/20958888/6309. Interesting read: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/why-not-preserve-file-permissions-td1619926.html

Comment: Problem was that at a certain commit the executable flag may be different from a previous commit, and before doing chmod I had to know what were the current permissions: I ended up using the first column of `git ls-tree -r master`.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is ooooooooold, but I found my own use-case for this functionality and looked around for a while for a better solution to this before combining a few solutions into a simple one-liner:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/dev git checkout $branch -- deploy.sh
```

In my case, I just wanted to be able to "peek" into some of my bare repositories without unpacking the whole thing (some of them are huge). People were talking about sparse checkouts and other such things, but I just needed one-off functionality. To check out just the "Documents/Health Records" folder, for example, I would do the following:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/tmp/my-files git checkout master -- "Documents/Health Records"
```

And lo! There it did appear.

Comment: So this was really useful for me as I'm trying to deploy a part of a monorepo after using Capistrano with `:repo_tree`. (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57360952/linking-to-multiple-subdirectories-using-repo-tree )

Answer (score 2):

This **git show** or similar **git cat-file blob** approaches work more-or-less fine for text files, but they are hopeless for binary files.

Better approach which works reliably for any kind of files and even allows to checkout entire folders:

```
git archive mybranch folder/file.txt --output result.tar
```

It creates a tar archive with desired content, exactly the file that sits in the source control. Works perfectly fine with binary files.

The only thing you need to do is to extract this tar file

```
tar -xf result.tar
```

See my [blogpost](http://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2013/02/27/git-checkout-on-bare-repo/) for more details