# Linking to multiple subdirectories using :repo_tree

Tags: capistrano

My repository is set up similar to the following:

```
repo_base
  - artwork
  - app
  - designsystem
  - api
```

Since each of the other folders in the repo (e.g. `app`, `api`, `designsystem`) depend on `artwork`, I have symlinks in place when running locally. This is working fine, as the path for `images` in the `designsystem` subdirectory is something like `../../artwork`. When you check out the repository, the entire tree is checked out, so the symlinks are pointing to the correct directory.

However, when I deploy with capistrano, I use `:repo_tree` to only deploy a portion of the overall monorepo. For example, the `deploy.rb` script for the `designsystem` folder looks like:

```
# config valid for current version and patch releases of Capistrano
lock "~> 3.11.0"

set :application, "designsystem"
set :repo_url, "git@gitlab.com:myuser/mymonorepo"
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/someplace.net/designsystem.someplace.net"
set :deploy_via, "remote_cache_with_project_root"
set :repo_tree, 'designsystem'
set :log_level, :error

before 'deploy:set_current_revision', 'deploy:buildMonolith'
```

The problem, of course, is that this only ends up deploying the `designsystem` subdirectory. Thus, the symlinks aren't valid, and are actually skipped in the building (`buildMonolith` step).

I'm wondering how I might go about having capistrano check out *another* subdirectory, `artwork`, and placing it somewhere in the repository source tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding a capistrano task called `assets.rb`:

```
require 'pathname'

##
# Import assets from a top level monorepo directory into the current working
# directory.
#
# When you use :repo_tree to deploy a specific directory of a monorepo, but your
# asset repository is in a different directory, you need to check out this
# top-level directory and add it to the deployment path. For example, if your
# monorepo directory structure looks something like:
#
# - /app
#   - src/
#     - assets -> symlink to ../../assets
# - /assets
# - /api
#
# And you want to deploy /app, the symlink to the upper directory won't exist if
# capistrano is configured to use :repo_tree "app". In order to overcome this,
# this task checks out a specified piece of the larger monorepo (in this case,
# the assets directory), and places it in the deployment directory at a
# specified location.
#
# Configuration:
# In your deploy/<stage>.rb file, you will need to specify two variables:
#   - :asset_path - The location within the deployment directory where the
#                   assets should be placed. Relative to the deployment working
#                   directory.
#   - :asset_source - The location of the top-level asset folder in the
#                     monorepo. Relative to the top level of the monorepo (i.e.
#                     the directory that would be used as a deployment if
#                     :repo_tree was not specified).
#
# In the above example, you would specify:
#
# set :asset_path, "src/assets"
# set :asset_source, "assets"
#
namespace :deploy do
  desc "Import assets from a top-level monorepo directory"
  task :import_assets do
   on roles(:all) do |host|
      within repo_path do
        final_asset_location = "#{release_path}/#{fetch(:asset_path)}"
        asset_stat_result = capture "stat", "-t", "#{final_asset_location}"
        asset_stat_result = asset_stat_result.split(" ")
        if asset_stat_result[0] == "#{final_asset_location}"
          info "Removing existing asset directory #{final_asset_location}..."
          execute "rm", "-rf", "#{final_asset_location}"
        end

        source_dir = Pathname.new(final_asset_location).parent.to_s
        info "Importing assets to #{source_dir}/#{fetch(:asset_source)}"
        execute "GIT_WORK_TREE=#{source_dir}", :git, "checkout", "#{fetch(:branch)}", "--", "#{fetch(:asset_source)}"

        info "Moving asset directory #{source_dir}/#{fetch(:asset_source)} to #{final_asset_location}..."
        execute :mv, "#{source_dir}/#{fetch(:asset_source)}", "#{final_asset_location}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It would be nice if I could somehow link into the `git` scm plugin, rather than calling `git` from the command line directly.