# git - Is git show safe to use on binary files when the output is redirected to a file?

Tags: git, git-show

I read that it's possible to retrieve a single file from a specific revision in Git, as answered in this SO question:
[How to retrieve a single file from specific revision in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610208/how-to-retrieve-a-single-file-from-specific-revision-in-git)

So I want to know if it's safe to do that with binary files. I have some binary files in use and I don't want to check them out, really what I want to do is copy them out from a specific revision. I tried this:

```
git show HEAD~1:database.db > copy-of-database-from-mmddyy.db
```

That seems to work, as in the output is an exact match of database.db for that commit. But I have to wonder is this an allowed use of `git show`? Does it support what I'm doing and will the result always be correct and not corrupt (ie autocrlf translation for example.. I'm in Windows msysgit). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, perfectly safe. From `git help show`:

> [For plain blobs, it shows the plain contents[ ... t]he contents of the blob objects are uninterpreted sequences of bytes. There is no encoding translation at the core level](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html).

And testing says the same thing: no attributes are applied.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to mark this as correct. Can you prepend a "Yes, it's fine" or something similar to your answer? I had to interpret it when I read it. If anyone stumbles on this question they'll probably want a simple Yes/No in addition to an explanation.