# Downloading the older version of zip file from Git

Tags: git

I have project.zip file which we commit in git. I made few changes in that zip contents and uploaded it in git repository. After that 2 commits were made. Now I need the zip file which I uploaded 2 commits before. Please help how can I download it. I tried using the below command, but it didn't work.

```
git cat-file <commit-hash>:./<file name> > aa.zip
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: @EdwardThomson : Actually I could not re-create/download that particular version of the zip file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `git log` to find the commit hash where the file has the contents you're interested in
2. `git checkout {hash that you found}`
3. the copy of the zip-file available on the filesystem is the one you're looking for (:

Comment: Ya I tried this. But is there any way without chekout method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610208/how-to-retrieve-a-single-file-from-specific-revision-in-git looks like it answers that question.

Comment: Your link gave me the answer. I used the below command as solution:                          `git checkout [branch | revision] filepath `