# Git: run validation script with before & after version of each modified file in a commit or in the working copy

Tags: git

After doing extensive modifications, I'd like to run a validation script to ensure the changes are correct: the changes are not quite trivial to perform mechanically, but are very easy to check.

To do that, I'd like the validation script to be called once per file modified, with the original & modified files as input. `git show $REV:$PATH` can probably get partway there (assuming no renames), but I wonder if there's something built in or easily accessible without "brute-forcing" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A  `git show commit_id --name-only` will list the files part of a commit.

That means, for each file, you can [retrieve a single file from a specific revision in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610208/6309).

You mentioned:

```
 git show $REV:$PATH
```

For the same path:

```
git show $REV~1:$PATH
```

That will give you the original content, before the (committed) modification