# How to create new branch with with previous changes, current changes and new file from another branch?

Tags: git, merge, git-branch

I have following files in my directory, let's say

> helloworld.go
>
> index.html
>
> main.js

These all are latest commit of branch `validation`.

Now I want to create a new branch which contains,

> helloworld.go <previously committed [particular hash] file in same branch>
>
> index.html [current branch's latest commit]
>
> main.js [file from another branch `newvalidation` in a particular commit]
>
> newone.c [file from another branch `newvalidation` in a particular commit]

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

First, don't use the [confusing and obsolete `git checkout` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309)

Use:

- [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) to create branch
- [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) to update files (as I [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/610315/6309))

Second, there are two approaches to your situation:

- either you create a new branch from where you are, then restore select files from an old commit: that works only if you have a *few* files to restore
- or you create a new branch from an old commit, and restore select files from `validation`: that works if you want everything from old commit, but a *few* files from validation

In the first case:

```
git switch -c newBranch validation
git restore -s <oldSHA1> -SW -- helloworld.go
git restore -s <oldSHA1> -SW -- main.js
git restore -s <oldSHA1> -SW -- newone.c
```

That will change the working tree and index directly, meaning all you need to do is a commit.

In the second case:

```
git switch -c newBranch <oldSHA1>
git restore -s validation -SW -- index.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

The general way to checkout a file at some commit commit is:

```
git checkout <SHA-1 of commit> path/to/your/file.ext
```

So, you may apply this for `helloworld.go`, `main.js`, and `newone.c`, i.e. use:

```
# from validation
git checkout -b validation_new
git checkout abc123 helloworld.go
git checkout def456 main.js
git checkout ghi789 newone.c
```

At this point, you may add the changes to the index and commit, if you wish.  If you need to find the SHA-1 hashes of the above three files, then you may use `git log` to do that.