# GIT branch checkout files not updated

Tags: git

I have a branch testbranch created from master  via GIT GUI.
Currently I am on master on GIT command line.

when I say  `"git branch -b testbranch"`  and `"git checkout testbranch"`   ,  it says it switched to the `testbranch` but the files are not updated.  I don't know why this strange behavior.

Also what is difference between  `git branch testbranch`  and `git branch -b testbranch`.

Answer (score 2):

That is why the old obsolete and confusing [`git checkout` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) has been replaced by:

- [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) ([presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309))
- [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) ([presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/610315/6309))

In your case, if the files are not correctly updated after a checkout, you can force them with:

```
git restore --source=HEAD --staged --worktree hello.c
```

(assuming you don't have any work in progress)

Answer (score -3):

I have found out the answer.

I just did below.  Simple.

```
rm -rf reporsitory
git clone repository
git checkout testbranch.
```

It worked.!

Git is supposed to make life simple.. But it is making it complex instead with ambiguous keywords and commands.    Why the hell on the earth can't we clone only a branch rather than the whole repo.  And why do we have two seperate commands to switch the branch and checkout the branch.

Comment: So... the xkcd approach (https://xkcd.com/1597/). I like it.

Comment: @Thanks for sharing the pic.. true story :)

Comment: Sorry, but I gotta downvote you. Git is confusing and sometimes a workaround helps, but providing it as the "answer" as to why things didn't really work is problematic because it just perpetuates the problem.