# How to refer to a file in another git branch?

Tags: git

I have a situation like this,

```
* 23e53d6 (master)  ---> a_config_file (original)
* f4e4dd2 ...
* 6308fc5 ...
|  
| * e52ec6b (hacky) ---> a_config_file (altered)
|/  
* 23e53d6 ...
```

and I would like to reference `a_config_file` on the `hacky` branch, while being on **any** branch and **without copying it**, to be used for a command, such as:

```
$ awesome_tool --config=hacky-branch-version-of-a-config-file <...>
```

Is this even possible? Some solutions I looked into:

- I know about `git restore --source=hacky a_config_file` but that copies that version of the file into the current working dir, overwriting the current one so it shows up in `git status`
- There is also `git show e52ec6b:a_config_file` but I can't use standard input or [process substitution](https://serverfault.com/questions/40284/create-virtual-file-from-bash-command-output) with the CLI tool of my choice so I would have to save the output (file, `mkfifo`, etc.) and invoke that - which is basically the previous item

---

I'm aware of the following questions, but these don't seem to provide a solution to this question:

- [How to get just one file from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364147/how-to-get-just-one-file-from-another-branch/2364223)
- [How to retrieve a single file from a specific revision in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610208/how-to-retrieve-a-single-file-from-a-specific-revision-in-git/610315#610315)

Please let me know if I overlooked something!)

Comment: Non-checked out files are not stored anywhere in a directly-useful format (i.e. they are stored either as lose blob objects or as part of a pack, but not in a way that's immediately useful). So you'll need to use `git show` or create a new checkout using `git worktree` to access the file. I think that with all of those restrictions you'll be restricted to simply piping the output of `git show` to a temporary path and pointing `awesome_tool` towards that temp file.

Comment: To be clear: Are you asking for a command line-only solution, or would checking out that particular commit and then copying over the file contents also be in play here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the governing limitations here are:

- **your tool of choice**:

  > I can't use standard input or process substitution with the CLI tool of my choice

  If the tool can only work with a real file on disk, then you need to create that file on disk.
- As [Joachim Sauer pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68223339/how-to-refer-to-a-file-in-another-git-branch#comments-68223339), "*Non-checked out files are not stored anywhere in a directly-useful format*".

  The *data* for the file obviously exists somewhere in git's database, but it's likely to be compressed into a "packfile", so not usable directly.

However, your conclusion that any file created would show up in `git status` is false, because you have full control over its name and location.

#### Approach 1: create the file outside the project directory

One approach would be to create a file outside the current directory, e.g. in `/tmp`. If you have access to the system's `mktemp` command, or an equivalent, you can safely automate that without choosing a file name. For instance, in a shell script:

```
OLDCONFIG="$(mktemp)"
git show e52ec6b:a_config_file > "$OLDCONFIG"
awesome_tool --config="$OLDCONFIG" <...>
rm -f "$OLDCONFIG"
```

#### Approach 2: use `.gitignore`

Alternatively, you could create a file in the current directory with a fixed name, and list that name in `.gitignore`. That way you don't even need a scripting language with variables, just fixed commands. For instance, add `a_config_file.old` to your `.gitignore` file, and then use this:

```
git show e52ec6b:a_config_file > a_config_file.old
awesome_tool --config=a_config_file.old <...>
rm -f a_config_file.old
```

Comment: Your initial observation is (unfortunately) astute, and it forms the full picture with [Joachim Sauer's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68223339/how-to-refer-to-a-file-in-another-git-branch#comments-68223339). I'm going to edit your answer to include it but please revert it if you don't agree, and will just post a separate supporting answer.  Thanks! (By the way, the same 2 solutions (out of dir copy & `.gitignore`) came into mind just before I saw your answer - and I really appreciate that you wrote it down with examples:)

Comment: Correction to my first sentence in my comment above: you also independently made the same argument as Joachim, but hope you won't mind crediting him as well as his comment preceded your answer.