# Git manually merge 2 commits that are not HEAD

Tags: git

If we have a branch with commits a -> b -> c (HEAD), and a, b has conflicts that cannot be auto-merged, how can we discard c and manually resolve the conflict of a and b again to produce a new commit?

Say in commit a, we have a file foo.txt. In commit b, we modified foo.txt (we we later regret) and added bar.txt. Then we have a bogus commit c. How to produce a commit with the a's version of foo.txt and with b's bar.txt present?

Comment: The wording of your question is slightly confusing to me.  If `a` and `b` _had_ merge conflicts, how is that relevant if in the end you have already made those commits?

Comment: Please give more details. How does a and b have conflicts. Are you trying to merge the branch you're talking about into a different branch? If so, how would disregarding commit c help with this? a and b would still cause conflicts during that merge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do an interactive rebase (as [illustrated here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#_changing_multiple)):

```
git rebase -i a~
```

In the "todo" list generated by this rebase, you would:

- `drop c`
- `squash b`
- `pick a`

`b` would be squashed with `a`, `c` would be no more.

---

For a more targeted approach:

> Say in commit a, we have a file `foo.txt`.
> In commit `b`, we modified `foo.txt` (that we later regret) and added `bar.txt`.
> Then we have a bogus commit `c`.
>
> How to produce a commit with the `a`'s version of `foo.txt` and with `b`'s bar.txt present?

You can easily restore a [file from any older commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/610315/6309):

```sh
# Before Git 2.24 (not recommeded, please upgrade Git)
git show <sha-a>/the/root/myfile.txt --output=myfile.txt
git add myfile.txt

# Git 2.24+
git restore -s <SHA1> -SW -- afile
# no git add needed: already done by restore -S (for staging)
```

You then make a new commit, with the right content restored.

Comment: Say in commit a, we have a file foo.txt. In commit b, we modified foo.txt (we we later regret) and added bar.txt. Then we have a bogus commit c. How to produce a commit with the a's version of foo.txt and with b's bar.txt present?

Comment: @Elucidase I have edited the answer to address your comment/edited question.