# git: send contents of a single file to stdout? like rcs/cvs -p

Tags: git, single-file

## BRIEF:  what is the best way in git to send the contents of a single file to STDOUT?

E.g.  the equivalent of `RCS co -p`, which *"[P]rints the retrieved revision on the standard output rather than storing it in the working file. This option is useful when co is part of a pipe."* --https://linux.die.net/man/1/co

Eg. similarly `cvs co -p` *"Pipe files to the standard output."* --https://linux.die.net/man/1/cvs"

E.g. in a  git work tree/clone, the equivalent of `cvs co -p some-relative-pathname`   which I can pipe into other commands.

E.g. the equivalent of `svn cat`.

E.g. `hg cat [OPTION]... FILE...`

### Why do I want to do this?

One reason, that prompted me to make this post, is that regrettably often I have to deal with UTF-16.XML,  and other formats that my tools do not support all that well ( UNIX-ish,  emacs,  cygwin, etc.).    I find myself  frequently doing things like  checking out the UTF-16, converting to UTF-8, editing UTF-8, savings UTF-8, wanting to diff ...  leading to a proliferation of temporary files.  Whereas with  RCS/CVS co -p  I was able to script a lot more of this. Of course I expect that somebody has already done this  for git, hence this question.

I actually want more than just  sending to STDOUT and thence to a pipeline.
I probably want to do things like  output to a specific  modified filename and so on.
But if you can do  STDOUT  you can write to any file,
whereas if you can only write to a non-stdout file,
while you *can*  then cat that  filed the STDOUT,
you have left a turd behind that  you have to clean up.
Plus you cannot do *-o tmp-file;cat tmp-file*  if you don't have filesystem write permissions.
Although writing directly to a file has the advantage that it can preserve file properties like permissions, and special stuff like symlinks.
Ideally both  output  content to STDOUT
as well as output to specified files  with properties as well as content.

## DETAIL:

### What makes a Best Way

By "best way" I mean a way that involves the least work.  Ideally just a single command line or pipeline (although obviously would script it if that is not possible).

Something that  keeps the simple cases simple, but can be extended to more complex cases.

Ideally does not involve  creating temporary clones or checkouts and then discarding them.  Ideally  does not modify the repository,  or create a temporary repository/clone.  (Believe it or not, At least one webpage suggests first "move all files in path/to to the repository root, then, remove all files except file.txt!!))

Ideally works when chdir'ed into a  git work tree. In this case  I would like to simply  specify a file pathname present in the local,  checked out tree. Relative to the current directory,  slightly suboptimally relative to the root of the repo,  submodule or super-project. But of course would like to be able to specify any normal git-tree-ish.

I.e. `XXX ./local-file`   equivalent to  `cvs co -p ./local-file`

Of course would like to be able to do this  when I'm not actually in such a repository, in a remote.  But for my current usage model that's just icing on the cake.

Ideally does not require a git-server  listening on localhost...   some systems do not consider that necessarily secure..

Minimally can output the contents of a single file.   Bonus points if it usefully  handle multiple files,  although that  raises the issue of how to do so:  just concatenate as `cvs -p` does,  losing file boundaries,  or emit something useful like a tar.

### Is this a duplicate question?

As far as I can tell this is not  a duplicate of Q1 [How to sparsely checkout only one single file from a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466735/how-to-sparsely-checkout-only-one-single-file-from-a-git-repository).

Or at least that Q&A thread  suffers from a lot of confusion: e.g.  whether Q1's OP actually wanted to do a checkout,  a sparse checkout,  or  did they just want to output the contents of the file.  Q1 sent me on on  a bit of a wild goose chase through `git archive`.

Closer:
Q2 [How to retrieve a single file from a specific revision in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610208/how-to-retrieve-a-single-file-from-a-specific-revision-in-git),
which arrives at `git show object`, and `git show $REV:$FILE`.

Although Q2's  question name  is very close to mine,
the answers  read on  are  mostly all relevant to Q2's first paragraph

> I have a Git repository and I'd like to see how some files looked a
> few months ago. I found the revision at that date; it's
> 27cf8e84bb88e24ae4b4b3df2b77aab91a3735d8. I need to see what one file
> looks like, and also save it as a ("new") file.

So they don't  mention the simplest thing
that is equivalent to `cvs co -p FILE` --- `git show HEAD:./FILE`.
If  Q2's  accepted answer  mentioned this I would delete my question -  but that looks like a significant change. (If I were maintaining an FAQ list I would do it, but not sure that that is appropriate  for StackOverflow.)

Perhaps   `git show HEAD:./file`  have been obvious to me,  but it wasn't.

In part because of the `git show HEAD:FILE`
---  root versus current working directory relative confusion.

Also because of some git show gotchas  that I mention in  the answer that I am supplying with my question,  such as
silent errors for files that do not exist
and confusing behavior for symlinks.

Both of these  and similar Q&As are full of  misleading wild goose chases.

E.g.  many suggested that `git archive` be used to do  this.
I was pursuing this wild goose  before switching back to `git show`.
I think that it might be inefficient to tar a directory and then extract a single file.
However I think it would be useful to have a `git archive` answer  that is substantially equivalent to `cvs -p`. Especially since this is probably the best way to extract  multiple files or a subtree.

However,  the biggest thrashing was everyone suggesting hashes that make your eyes bleed,
rather than simply using HEAD or  some similar.
Many of these answers  probably work in the general case,
where you are not extracting a single file from a working tree,
but  are overkill for some of the simple cases that I am most interested in.
What I really needed was a refresher on https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions

- I am pretty sure  I knew the answer to this question in the past,
  but did not know it off the top of my head,
  and basically  searching for it a fresh lead to a lot of  wasted time, wild goose chases w/wo   dead ends,  and so on.

It's not enough to have  the  right answer  implied but possibly obscure,
or even explicit  but hidden in a way such that standard searches don't find it,
or find it far down the list with lots of other  off target answers.

### I may have found an answer before posting the question...

My efforts to  provide background information for this question (to avoid accusations of not  having tried to figure it out myself and mostly to  annoying pseudo-answers  that miss the point or  are incomplete or just plain wrong)  led me to eventually find what I think is the BKM:

`git show HEAD:./git-file-cwd-relative-pathname` == `cvs co -p some-relative-pathname`.

`git show HEAD:./git-root-relative-pathname` == `cvs co -p ...`,  where it is a bit more work in CVS/RCS to get such a pathname relative to a project root.

I will post this this  question and immediately answer it myself.

I think it is worth  posting this if only try to make it easier for somebody else to find this answer quickly. I did not find it quickly,  even though pieces of it are scattered around other Q&A threads.  Also avoid some  wild goose chases.

### What do you call this operation?

"Extract"?

My first thought was to ask for "how to extract the contents of a single file from git".  But googling that finds many posts and webpages that "checkout" or "pull".

"extract-file-markdown" looked promising, but clicking through
https://gist.github.com/ssp/1663093#file-git-extract-file-markdown
the title is
"How to extract a single file with its history from a git repository".
Whereas what I am trying to do is "extract a single file WITHOUT its history."
Well, at least the author of that tool  made that clear after only one level of onion peeling click.

The term "extract"  leads to confusion.

Hence  the title that I'm providing to this question: "send contents of a single file to stdout".
With "like rcs/cvs -p"  to further reduce ambiguity.

Yada yada yada ...  in a current working tree, or from  a remote repository ...  when you just have a  file pathname relative to the current working directory, not necessarily the git repo route ...  yada yada yada....

Probably the closest existing answer used the word "retrieve"  a single file, which neither I nor Google thought was equivalent.   I only found that answer a day or so later, after had written almost all of this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## WIP: cleaning up -1 answer since no better available

More than a year later: Nobody seems to be volunteering to provide a better answer to this, so I will incrementally clean it up.  Mostly, incorporating @torek's comments, trying to make them understandable, and provide a quick compact answer that doesn't require looking at a lot of manpages and putting the pieces together.

(I am not disputing the -1 score, I was just hoping that somebody could provide a clean answer.  Where "clean" means not  that the solution suggested by @torek is incorrect,  not even  with regards to inelegantcies like error codes,  but where those suggestions from comments are actually formulated as a compact answer.)

## `git cat-file -p <rev>:<cwd-or-root-relative-pathname>`  is probably the answer

### Simplest case: CWD relative, as checked out

The closest thing to `cvs co -p <cwd-relative-pathname>`

- seems to be `git cat-file -p HEAD:./<cwd-relative-pathname>`
- with close contender `git show HEAD:./<cwd-relative-pathname>`

differing in some ways.

### Specifying Revision

Both CVS and GIT can  specify or request a revision in many different ways.

CVS examples:  a numeric version number like `-r 1.2.3.4`, or  more human friendly `-r named-tag`,  with special tags like HEAD and BASE. `-D date`, etc.

GIT has many more different ways of specifying or requesting revisions. Ranging from relatively user-friendly stuff like HEAD and HEAD^, through SHA-1 160-bit 40-hex-digit hashcodes like d08c8b53975f513ad3b320bf55273b852f25247c that you can abbreviate with the 1st few hex digits,  with many places in between.

CVS defaults to the current revision if you say `cvs co -p some-relative-pathname`

GIT does not default this way, so explicitly  providing a git revision like HEAD:  or any of  the umpteen other possible formats is usually required. It is rather pleasant that GIT allows revspecs like HEAD: to be concatenated to the pathname by colon. If you do not specify  something like HEAD:  you might not get anything, no output, no error messages.

Summing up:

The closest thing to `cvs co -r CVS_REV -p <cwd-relative-pathname>`

- seems to be
  `git cat-file -p GIT_REVSPEC:./<cwd-relative-pathname>`
- similarly for `git show...`

With variations like `cvs co -D date...` <--> ...

### CWD vs repo ROOT relative pathnames

In CVS `cvs co -p a/b/c` defaults to interpreting the path relative  to the current working directory CWD.  If you wanted to be relative to the "root" of the repository, you have to do some work

In git `git cat-file -p HEAD:a/b/c` Is interpreted not relative to CWD, but relative to the root of the repository.

In git,  to specify  relative to the current working directory, you need to say `./`, e.g. `git cat-file -p HEAD:./a/b/c`. For that matter `../` also works.  This is a fairly common convention nowadays, although it will break any scripts that assume  that prepending `./` to  any  pathname that does not begin with `/`  is effectively a NOP.

You can get the GIT root relative pathname via something like `git ls-files <cwd-relative-pathname>`. In CVS ... well,  in CVS/RCS  it is a bit more work to get such a pathname relative to a project root. RCS  does not really have  the concept of a "project root"  and depends on other tools wrapped around basic RCS. This can happen even with CVS, or at least would be happening if people were still using CVS.

Therefore:

The closest thing to `cvs co -p <cwd-relative-pathname>`

- seems to be `git cat-file -p HEAD:./<cwd-relative-pathname>`
- similarly for `git show...`

The closest thing to `cvs co -p <root-relative-pathname>`

- seems to be `git cat-file -p HEAD:<cwd-relative-pathname>`
- similarly for `git show...`

TBD: I may provide  examples of some  confusing error messages,  or, worse, examples where you get no error message or status code  but you are still doing  the wrong thing.

TBD:  Example if you accidentally provide an absolute path to GIT.

### That's All

That's all I was really looking for.  Modulo obvious extensions to use remote repositories, fixup the git show formatting, etc.  However, rather than ending the answer here, I hope that it might help somebody else to see some of the dead ends that I went through -  things that I need to be careful of in shell scripts  and Makefile's using this.  Some shell session extracts, edited for clarity.

## Old stuff kept around, to be cleaned up

I don't want to completely eliminate the stuff below yet,  because some of the gotchas are still relevant.   But I do want to rework it

## `git show` silent failures and other surprises

### `git show NO-SUCH-FILE` =>  silent error

> cwd1> `git show README`
> --> No output, not even an error code

That's  disappointing, but I know enough about  git revisions to try`HEAD:README`

> cwd1>  `git show HEAD:README.Dragon_Stuff` 
> *fatal: path 'some-dir/README' exists, but not 'README'* 
> *hint: Did you mean 'HEAD:some-dir/README' aka 'HEAD:./some-dir/README'*

That's a useful error message, and even provides an error code :-)

> cwd1> `git show HEAD:./README.Dragon_Stuff` ...
> *...* 
> --> yay! I get the output

That's not too bad. It is annoying not to have error codes if the
object not found, i.e. will probably lead to bugs and scripts that use
this, but that can be added.

### `git show SYMLINKs` =>  more silent confusion

... In a different directory `cwd2` where the README was a symlink.

First, the usual:

> $ cwd2>  `git show README`  -->  no output, no error code :-(
> $ cwd2>  `git show ./README`  -->  no output, no error code :-(

> $ cwd2>  `git show HEAD:./README`
> *some-dir/README*
> --> Huh?
> Oh, it's a symlink:  *./README -> some-dir/README*.
> Git show is outputting the target of the link.
> Which can be easily confused with the contents of a text file.
> Q:  is there an option to reduce such confusion?

(BTW,  I did this on cygwin, whose symlink handling is *interesting*.
It might be different on Linux.  I haven't checked.  Either case would be unfortunate.)

### `git show ROOT-and-LOCAL` =>  more silent confusion

> $ cwd2>  `cd some-dir`
> $ some-dir>  `git show README` -->  no output, no error code 
> $ some-dir>  `git show ./README` --> no output no error code

> $ some-dir>  `git show HEAD:README`
> *some-dir/README*
> --> Huh?

In this example cwd2 just happened to be the root of the repository.

But even if cwd2 is not the repo-root, it can happen that there might be a  repo-root/README
that might also be a symlink.  I don't know if it would be more confusing to point to some-dir/README or some-other-dir/README.

> $ some-dir>  `git show HEAD:./README` 
> *...*
> --> Yay! The actual contents!

Comment: `git show` makes partial use of `git diff` so some invocations run `git diff` and pass file name arguments to `git diff` to filter things. Hence `git show README` runs `git diff` on the parent and the current commit, selects the changed `README` file, and shows that—but if there's no change to `README`, the diff is empty, so `git show` shows the empty diff = nothing. The diff worked fine, there was just nothing, so exit status = 0.

Comment: To resolve this, *always* use `HEAD:` or `<commit>:` or just `:` to force `git show` to look in a commit or in the index (`:foo` means "file foo as it appears in the index"). You can also use `git rev-parse` to check for existence, e.g., `git rev-parse HEAD:foo` will give you the hash ID of entity `foo` in the `HEAD` commit, if there is such an entity. If there is no such entity it gives an error, so now you know "no such entity". The `./` vs full path stuff is ... annoying: Git is not consistent about when it enforces this, with various commands.

Comment: So: use `git rev-parse` to find a hash ID. Then optionally use `git cat-file -t <hash-id>` to find the type of object: if it's a "tree" object, there's a whole directory full of files here. If it's a "blob" object, it's either a symlink or a file. Given a `<commit>:<path>` syntax, tree and blob are the only possibilities.

Comment: Finally: there's also `git cat-file -p` to print a human-readable representation of *any* Git object. Normally you might give it a raw hash ID; for a blob object, it prints out the file's content. But like most Git programs, it will rev-parse anything, so you can `git cat-file -p HEAD:path/to/file.ext`. Experiment a bit, observe how show and cat-file treat `./` differently...

Comment: @torek: thanks for your comment. Do you mean that “git show HEAD^:./file” is not guaranteed to print the contents of the file in HEAD^ if it has not changed? I do not see how an empty diff would be relevant to the exit status for a file does not exist in the repository or the local work tree. // although I should perhaps have said that I would like the exit status of any such gIt equivalent of svn/hg cat or CVS/RCS co -p to match. To facilitate substituting it in existing scripts or make files

Comment: No: when using the `<rev>:<path>` syntax, `git show` *always* shows a content (or fails). It's just that `git show README` means "show me the diff of the README, with respect to the parent": sort of a fancified version of `git diff HEAD^ HEAD -- README`. (The `git show` command handles *merge commits* which invoke Git's "combined diff" algorithm. Combined diff is documented and is ... a little complicated...)

Comment: There's one last bout of craziness, which has never been in RCS/CVS because those are *Unix* tools: Git has the option of doing LF -> CRLF translation on output (during the extract-file-from-repository phase), which of course exists because Windows. The `git show` command by default *obeys* any directives you have in place for doing this kind of translation, while `git cat-file -p` by default *does not obey* this. There are flags to make `git cat-file -p` do it, but because it's triggered based on path name, `git cat-file -p` with a blob hash ID literally *can't* . There's more, but no space.