# how can I list all the different versions of a file, and diff them also?

Tags: git

using git, I want to list all the different revisions of a given file.

Then, I want to choose a particular version and compare it when another.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 50):

To show a history of changes to a particular file, you can use `git log`:

```
git log -p -- path/to/file
```

The `-p` tells it to show the diff between each revision and its parent. To get a cumulative diff between two revisions, take the ID of the two revisions, and pass them to `git diff`:

```
git diff abc123 def456 -- path/to/file.
```

Where `abc123` and `def456` are the revision IDs.

Comment: `-p` stands for [`--patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#:~:text=Generate%20patch) for the curious—also, why is `git log -h` so short and unhelpful? 

Answer (score 32):

You can use a script like this to dump all the versions of a file to a separate file:

e.g.

```
git_all_versions_of path/to/somefile.txt
```

It will generate a bunch of files in the same folder as the original file, named like the following, with the most recent change postfixed with "1". Note that it will also dump another file ending in `.logmsg` that has the log message of the commit as well.

```
path/to/somefile.txt.1.0dea419
path/to/somefile.txt.1.0dea419.logmsg
path/to/somefile.txt.2.cdea8s9
path/to/somefile.txt.2.cdea8s9.logmsg
path/to/somefile.txt.3.fdsf2d
path/to/somefile.txt.3.fdsf2d.logmsg
etc...
```

After I've dumped all the files, I just run a `grep -r DELETED_METHOD_NAME somefile.txt.*` to find what I'm looking for.

### git_all_versions_of

```sh
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ] || [ "$1" == "help" ]
then
  echo "dump all git versions of a file to separate files"
  echo 
  echo "usage: $0 FILENAME";
  echo 
  echo "e.g."
  echo 
  echo "$ $0 path/to/somefile.txt"
  echo 
  echo "path/to/somefile.txt.1.0dea419"
  echo "path/to/somefile.txt.1.0dea419.logmsg"
  echo "path/to/somefile.txt.2.cdea8s9"
  echo "path/to/somefile.txt.2.cdea8s9.logmsg"
  echo "path/to/somefile.txt.3.fdsf2d"
  echo "path/to/somefile.txt.3.fdsf2d.logmsg"
  echo "..."
  exit 1
fi

index=1
for commit in $(git log --pretty=format:%h "$1")
do
  padindex=$(printf %03d "$index")
  out="$1.$padindex.$commit"
  log="$out.logmsg"
  echo "saving version $index to file $out for commit $commit"
  echo "*******************************************************" > "$log"
  git log -1 --pretty=format:"%s%nAuthored by %an at %ai%n%n%b%n" "$commit" >> "$log"
  echo "*******************************************************" >> "$log"
  git show "$commit:./$1" > "$out"
  let index++
done
```

Comment: Also git_log_short [git_log_message_for_commit & choose_col] are not found

Comment: No, the function git_log_short is not defined anywhere in this script.

Comment: Life saver! Git foo is here.

Comment: I fixed the above errors mentioned by Wolfgang and Alex, and have included the fixes in the script

Comment: HUGE +1 for providing a reasonably documented end-to-end script as an answer to a SO question.  THANKS !!!!

Answer (score 16):

Use the standard GUI tool of git:

```
 gitk --all -- path/to/file
```

It displays the version history stripped down to the commits that affect `path/to/file`.

As display mode for the comparison between the current (*new*) version and the preceding (*old*) version you can choose:

- *old version* or
- *new version* or
- *diff*

Additionally, you can select a commit and then right click another commit and choose *Diff this -> selected* in the context menu. Everything that you wished for.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a tool that would get you most of the way there (printing out the entire contents of a file, as it was in SHA-1-WHATEVER.

[git-cat](http://github.com/rwilcox/git-cat/)

You could either put a little shell script over that to do everything automatically, or the README.markdown file in that repository also gives references to where I learned all the stuff I needed to write the command.