# How to find an existing old file in git repo

Tags: git

If I have a repo located in c:\myrepo\source and a file in the repo named myfile.txt with multiple versions and I have an old copy of myfile.txt in another folder eg c:\temp\myfile.txt is it possible to check if that version exists in the repo without copying it over the current file ?

Comment: Check if the blob ID exists already? It's a trivial header and sha ... maybe harder on windows where you don't have basic tools available.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48027778/447503

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to obtain the blob id for the file:

```
c:\myrepo\source>git hash-object "c:\temp\myfile.txt"
f70d6b139823ab30278db23bb547c61e0d4444fb
```

Then you can use the id to find the path and the commit where it was added.

With git 2.16+ it's easy:

```
c:\myrepo\source>git describe --always f70d6b139823ab30278db23bb547c61e0d4444fb
e76967c:path/to/myfile.txt
```

For older git versions you will need a script to crawl all the commits and trees to find this blob as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/223890/447503

For text files there's a caveat when there's different CRLF normalization (the default one and in the repo). Then `git hash-object` may print a wrong value.

On Cygwin, for example, this will help:

```
$ git hash-object "c:\temp\myfile.txt"
4a2cdc2c8fc21f625d69b9b9197004fbbd2de76b
basin@BASIN /cygdrive/c/myrepo/source
$ git -c core.autocrlf=true hash-object "c:\temp\myfile.txt"
f70d6b139823ab30278db23bb547c61e0d4444fb
```

Comment: Looking for the hash is more efficient than my answer. +1. Note, you don't need Cygwin. A simple bash session is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- [dump all versions of a versioned file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32849134/6309) in a folder outside your Git repository
- for each of those file, you make a normal diff (not git diff) with your own old copy.

If one of those diff is empty, you know your old copy was already versioned.