# Equivalent in git of "hg cat" or "svn cat"

Tags: git, version-control

I want to extract a copy of the latest version of a file held in a git repository, and pass it into a script for some processing.  With svn or hg, I just use the "cat" command:

> Print the specified files as they were at the given revision. If
>   no revision is given, the parent of the working directory is used,
>   or tip if no revision is checked out.

(that's from the description of hg cat in the hg documentation)

What's the equivalent command to do this with git?

Comment: My final solution was to first use "git ls-files --full-name <filepath>" to get the full path relative to the top of the repository, and then "git show HEAD:<full filepath>"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve a single file from specific revision in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610208/how-to-retrieve-a-single-file-from-specific-revision-in-git)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a quick git command to see an old version of a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338436/is-there-a-quick-git-command-to-see-an-old-version-of-a-file)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

```
git show rev:path/to/file
```

Where *rev* is the revision.

See http://git.or.cz/course/svn.html for a comparison of git and svn commands.

Comment: This works for me, yay!  (Using HEAD as the revision)  I think I need to use the path relative to the top of the repository, which is a bit of a pain, but workable.

Comment: @Richard Boulton: this is less painful if using tab completition

Comment: @pimlottc worked fine for me without the ./ - might depend on git version

Comment: the link  http://git.or.cz/course/svn.html  returns 403 forbidden -

Answer (score 11):

there is "git cat-file" which you can run like this:

`$ git cat-file blob v1.0:path/to/file`

where you can replace 'v1.0' with the branch, tag or commit SHA you want and then 'path/to/file' with the relative path in repository. You can also pass '-s' to see the size of the content if you want.

might be closer to the 'cat' commands you are used to, though the previously mentioned 'show' will do much the same thing.

Answer (score 8):

`git show` is the command you are looking for.  From the documentation:

```
   git show next~10:Documentation/README
          Shows the contents of the file Documentation/README as they were
          current in the 10th last commit of the branch next.
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work: running "git show next~1:README" produces

fatal: ambiguous argument 'next~1:README': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions

Comment: Do you have a branch called 'next'?  If you want the current branch, use 'HEAD' instead.

Answer (score 3):

Use **[`git show`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html)**, as in `git show commit_sha_id:path/to/some/file.cs`.

Answer (score 3):

Also work with branch names (like HEAD in the 1st p) :

```
git show $branch:$filename
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a git cat shell script, which is [up on github](http://github.com/rwilcox/git-cat)

Comment: Looking at the code for that was helpful, though I wanted a standalone python script, and didn't need all the features of git cat.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be a *direct* substitute. [This blog entry](http://buildmonkey.wordpress.com/2009/05/12/no-svn-cat-in-git/) details how to do the equivalent by determining the *latest* commit, then determining the hash for the file in that commit, and then dumping it out.

```
git log ...
git ls-tree ...
git show -p ...
```

(the blog entry has typos and uses the above with the command `svn`)

Comment: Blog entry was helpful, despite the typos.

Answer (score 0):

None of the `git show` suggestions truly satisfy because (try as I might), I can not find a way not to get the metadata cruft from the top of the output. The spirit of cat(1) is just to show the contents.
This (below) takes a file name and an optional number. The number is how commits you want to go back. (Commits that changed that file. Commits that do not change the target file are not counted.)

```
gitcat.pl filename.txt
gitcat.pl -3 filename.txt
```

shows the contents of filename.txt as of the latest commit of filename.txt and the contents from 3 commits before that.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use FileHandle;
use Cwd;

# Have I mentioned lately how much I despise git?

(my $prog = $0) =~ s!.*/!!;
my $usage = "Usage: $prog [revisions-ago] filename\n";

die( $usage ) if( ! @ARGV );
my( $revision, $fname ) = @ARGV;

if( ! $fname && -f $revision ) {
    ( $fname, $revision ) = ( $revision, 0 );
}

gitcat( $fname, $revision );

sub gitcat {
    my( $fname, $revision ) = @_;

    my $rev = $revision;
    my $file = FileHandle->new( "git log --format=oneline '$fname' |" );

    # Get the $revisionth line from the log.
    my $line;
    for( 0..$revision ) {
        $line = $file->getline();
    }

    die( "Could not get line $revision from the log for $fname.\n" ) 
        if( ! $line );

    # Get the hash from that.
    my $hash = substr( $line, 0, 40 );
    if( ! $hash =~ m/ ^ ( [0-9a-fA-F]{40} )/x ) {
        die( "The commit hash does not look a hash.\n" );
    }

    # Git needs the path from the root of the repo to the file because it can
    # not work out the path itself.
    my $path = pathhere();
    if( ! $path ) {
        die( "Could not find the git repository.\n" );
    }

    exec( "git cat-file blob $hash:$path/'$fname'" );
}


# Get the path from the git repo to the current dir.
sub pathhere {
    my $cwd = getcwd();
    my @cwd = split( '/', $cwd );
    my @path;

    while( ! -d "$cwd/.git" ) {
        my $path = pop( @cwd );
        unshift( @path, $path );
        if( ! @cwd ) {
            die( "Did not find .git in or above your pwd.\n" );
        }
        $cwd = join( '/', @cwd );
    }
    return join( '/', map { "'$_'"; } @path );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using bash the following is a useful function:

```
gcat () { if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then echo "Usage: $FUNCNAME [rev] file"; elif [ $# -lt 2 ]; then git show HEAD:./$*; else git show $1:./$2; fi }
```

Put it in your `.bashrc` file (you can use whatever name you like other than `gcat`.

Example usage:

```
> gcat
Usage: gcat [rev] file
```

or

```
> gcat subdirectory/file.ext
```

or

```
> gcat rev subdirectory/file.ext
```