# Fetch specific file from repository using GIT

Tags: git, version-control

I would like to checkout a single file from a remote git-repository.

Is there a way to checkout a single file from a remote git-repository, without checking out the other commits?

EDIT:

Following the answers, I've realized that i can do a git fetch, and then a git checkout origin/branch path/to/file, which works great.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178389/browse-and-display-files-in-a-git-repo-without-cloning

Comment: The terminology in your question is confusing - do you want to *fetch* or *checkout* a single file? You can *fetch* from a remote repo without affecting your working tree, then you can *checkout* one particular file into your working tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071288/equivalent-in-git-of-hg-cat-or-svn-cat) shows a few solutions, including `git show` and `git cat-file`.

```
git show rev:path/to/file
```

If you want to retrieve the contents into a file, you'll need redirect `stdout` appropriately.