# Get the HEAD version of a given file for streaming processing/diffing

Tags: git, version-control, diff, git-diff

I'm generating a LaTeX document. I want to run a specialised [`latexdiff`](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/02/16/using-latexdiff-for-marking-changes-to-tex-documents.html) to compare my current (uncommitted) version against the last commit of a file, `paper.tex`.

Something like:

```
latexdiff paper.tex HEAD:paper.tex > diff.tex
```

However I've got no idea what the `HEAD:paper.tex` would actually be. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

*TL;DR* [`git show HEAD:repo/path/to/paper.tex` `cat`s the contents of the HEAD version.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071288/equivalent-in-git-of-hg-cat-or-svn-cat)

Not sure if it's the best answer in general, as it appears `latexdiff` doesn't handle input piping sensibly, but the below is a reasonable use case in my scenario.

```
git show HEAD:repo/path/to/paper.tex > head.tex; latexdiff paper.tex head.tex > diff.tex; rm head.tex; latexmk diff.tex; evince diff.pdf
```