# Is that possible to see a file in a specific commit from Github desktop locally than the difference?

Tags: git, github-for-windows

In Gitlab/Github, if I use it remotely, I can download a file in a specific commit, by going to the commits and browser the repository at that commit.

If I use the Github desktop on windows with the repository on my PC (not push it to the remote), I tried to see a specific commit, I only find the difference of versions. But nowhere to see the entire file at that specific commit. Is there any method for doing it?

Comment: "Is there any method for doing it?" Yes, there is. (Well, I know how to do it from the command line. I don't use GitHub Desktop.)

Comment: Tell me please, as long as it is locally ^_^

Comment: You would say `git show commit:filepath`.

Comment: I had a commit, name "2nd" and a file `1.txt`. I tried `git show 2nd:/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/test-a/test-a/1.txt`, got `fatal: invalid object name 'commit'` :( I may omit `1.txt`, same result

Comment: Your commit is not named `2nd`. A commit message is not a name. Its name is more like `ae93b60d`.

Comment: Thanks. I found `e39...` on Github Desktop, and I used `git show e39...:/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/test-b/test-b/1.txt`, got `fatal: path '/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/test-b/test-b/1.txt' exists on disk, but not in 'e39...'`

Comment: Well now your path is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is followed by [desktop/desktop issue 6535](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/6535) (for binary file, or any other type actually)

From 2019:

> The biggest problem here is that while we can easily display the diff of changes in a repository, opening a specific version of a file is not easy - either we'd need to checkout that commit so the working directory has that version, or we extract the specific version of the file to a temporary location, which the default program can then open.
>
> Here's a rough flow I can think of that might achieve this:
>
> - In "History" view, find a commit with an older version of the file you're interested in opening
> - When the user clicks to perform the action, Desktop will extract the blob from the repository to the OS temporary directory, using a pattern like {SHA}-{filename} so that we can avoid clashes if the user looks at multiple versions of a file
> - Once that file exists on disk, perform the existing behaviour of opening this new file in the default program

In command-line, you could use [`git show REVISION:path/to/file`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/338470/6309) or [`git cat-file -p <sha1>:./file.tex > wherever.tex`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14996309/6309).

In your case:

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/test-b
git show e39...:test-b/1.txt
```

Meaning: the path in [`git show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) should be the one from the root folder of the repository, not the OS full path.

The [OP Redzeń](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17794416/redze%C5%84) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528190/is-that-possible-to-see-a-file-in-a-specific-commit-from-github-desktop-locally/70528479?noredirect=1#comment124673365_70528479):

```
cd  test-b, 
# pwd: /mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/test-b/test-b
git show e39...:1.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to cd to the root folder of the repository, and `git show e39...:test-b/1.txt` and got `fatal: path 'test-b/1.txt' does not exist in 'e39...'`

Comment: I just tried to `cd test-b`, now I am at `/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/test-b/test-b`, and `git show e39...:1.txt`, it works!!

Comment: @Redzeń Well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: `git show` works!