# How can I see the unmodified, HEAD version of a file with Git without stashing?

Tags: git

I'm working on staging some modified content to the index, and I'd like to see how the previous commit looks without stashing. I am aware of `git stash`'s `--keep-index` option, but would rather not stash if possible. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a quick git command to see an old version of a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338436/is-there-a-quick-git-command-to-see-an-old-version-of-a-file)

Comment: The answer I provide is among the answers to that question, but I think my question itself is different as it relates to stashing.

Comment: @dimadima but it doesn't relate to stashing...

Comment: @hobbs: it relates to _not_ stashing. anyway, take it or leave it :). vote dupe if you want to close it. i had wanted to create an easily google-able Q/A after not easily finding the answer to this myself.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
git show :path/to/file
```

That is, `git show` with a `:` prepended to the path of the file you want to see.

This behavior is described in the [gitrevisions](http://jk.gs/gitrevisions.html) manpage.

Comment: `cat-file -p` does the same. You could also `git diff HEAD -- path/to/file` (allthough that strictly gives you a diff, not the original file)

Comment: @dimadima what is it that you find confusing?

Comment: @Cupcake: A bunch of things. It's nearly impossible to read non-linearly. And non-linearity aside, take this for example: "A colon, optionally followed by a stage number (0 to 3) and a colon". Nowhere else in the manpage is a "stage number" mentioned. And I've never heard of "stage number" within the context of Git altogether, actually.