# In git, how do I view a previous version of an image file?

Tags: image, git, git-show

I know I can [git-show the previous version of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338436/is-there-a-quick-git-command-to-see-an-old-version-of-a-file), but I've got **images** in my repository! When I `git show <revision>:<path-to-image>`, it unhelpfully opens them in a pager...

It seems `git show` doesn't consider environment variables for this: I've tried setting `EDITOR=gimp` and `PAGER=gimp`, even `VISUAL=gimp` to no effect. I can't find anything in `man git show` about changing the pager application either.

As a workaround, I can `git stash save` my current changes, `git checkout` the revision, open the file, `checkout` back to where I was and `git stash apply`, but that's a lot of effort that shouldn't be.

How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try piping it to gimp:

```
git show <revision>:<path-to-image> | gimp
```

Comment: Elegant! This works great for GIMP because it reads `stdin`. (For image editors that don't, `> /tmp/a.png` and open from there, I guess.)