# Is there a single git command to retrieve an old version of a file?

Tags: git, sh

In git, we can use `git show commitlike:filepath` to show a file as it was at a particular revision, and using shell redirection we can retrieve that version and put it back in the working tree somewhere: `git show commitlike:filepath > otherpath`.

Is there a single git command to perform the latter task? `git checkout commitlike -- filename` can retrieve the file but only put it in its original location.

Comment: There might be some clever way to do it with the plumbing commands, but `git show` and redirection seems like the most sensible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a quick git command to see an old version of a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338436/is-there-a-quick-git-command-to-see-an-old-version-of-a-file)

Comment: Not a duplicate, I want to put the file back in the working tree not display its contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git config --global alias.getfile '!sh -c '"'"'git show $1:$2 > $3'"'"' -'
```

Then you can do this:

```
$ git getfile COMMITLIKE FILE_PATH DESTINATION_FILE
```

For example:

```
$ git getfile HEAD~3 .gitignore old_gitignore
```