# Git show's file path

Tags: git

Let's say I have a git repo for my stuffs inside a directory `myapp`:

```
myapp
    /.git
    /.gitignore
    /subdirA
        /subdirB
            /file1.txt
            /file2.txt
            /(and some other stuffs)
    /(and some other stuffs)
```

I want to view `file1.txt` from an old commit `abcd123`. For [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338436/is-there-a-quick-git-command-to-see-an-old-version-of-a-file), I learnt that I should use something like:

```
$ git show abcd123:path/to/file1.txt
```

However, I am confused about the right path to use. I've tried something like

```
$ git show abcd123:myapp/subdirA/subdirB/file1.txt
$ git show abcd123:subdirA/subdirB/file1.txt
$ git show abcd123:subdirB/file1.txt
$ git show abcd123:file1.txt
```

but git keeps giving me error messages like

```
$ Path 'subdirA/subdirB/file1.txt' does not exist in 'abcd123'
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You can get a list of valid paths int he commit with `git ls-tree -r --name-only abcd123`

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Thanks a lot. It works. I can view the file I need now. In the above example the path "subdirA/subdirB/file1.txt" should be correct, but I probably have typed the path wrongly so that I got an error message.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley this is worth writing an answer )

Comment: amazing question but you can explain why you want to see the files from the a older commit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This command will generate a list of paths that exist in comment `abcd123`:

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only abcd123
```

Anything you get from that command should work as a path for `git show abcd123:...`

Also, it's easier sometimes to use a leading `./` on the path. That automatically replaces the `.` with the path from the repository root to your current directory in the working tree. For example:

```
cd ~/my-git-repo/dir1/dir2
git show abcd123:./Makefile # equivalent to git show abcd123:dir1/dir2/Makefile
```

If you try `git show abcd123:Makefile` it doesn't work... but git does suggest ("Did you mean...?") both the version with the full path from the repository root and the version with the `./` ... unless you also have a `Makefile` in the root directory of `abcd123` in which case you just get that with no warning that you might have wanted `./Makefile` instead.