# Specific Git file version to specific folder

Tags: git

I have a Git repository and I would like to see how a file looked at a specific commit.

So to retrieve all commits of a file, I am using git log [filepath].
With git log, the application retrieves the commits and their SHA values.

What is/ are the Git command(s) to retrieve the file of a specific commit?

So in pseudo code:

1. Get all commits of a file (already implemented)
2. Retrieve file of a commit SHA
3. Export file to a specific folder.

**I already tried**:

```
git show [SHA OF COMMIT] -- [REPODIRECTORY]
git show [SHA OF COMMIT]:[FILEPATH] > [NEW LOCATON]
```

That gave:

```
Error: fatal: Path 'D://Test//FolderName//FolderName//MyTestFile.cs' exists on disk, 
but not in 'a2f3f51ee27d5711d2974f0256b4eed0b3225d44'.
```

- [How to retrieve a single file from specific revision in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610208/how-to-retrieve-a-single-file-from-specific-revision-in-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git show [SHA OF COMMIT]:[FILEPATH] > [NEW LOCATON]` should be the right syntax.

But `[FILEPATH]` should be the [path from the root of the repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/338470/6309), not the absolute file path form the host drive disk.

From [`gitrevisions` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions):

```
<rev>:<path>, e.g. HEAD:README, :README, master:./README
```

> A suffix `:` followed by a path names the blob or tree at the given path in the tree-ish object named by the part before the colon.
>   `:path` (with an empty part before the colon) is a special case of the syntax described next: content recorded in the index at the given path.
>   A path starting with `./` or `../` is relative to the current working directory. The given path will be converted to be relative to the working tree’s root directory.

---

In your case:

```
cd /d D:\Test\MyRepoFolder
git show a2f3f51ee27d5711d2974f0256b4eed0b3225d44:test.css > anotherpath\test.css
```

You would use `:test.css`, not `:D://...` (the absolute file path).
The root of the repo is "`D:\Test\MyRepoFolder`".
Hence, the path to access `test.css` should relative to that root.

In the OP's instance, the exact path of the file was `ReactiveUI\afile`, and the repo was in `D:\Test\ReactiveUI` hence a bit of confusion.

Even though the root folder was named `ReactiveUI`, the command to use was:

```
git show <sha1>:ReactiveUI/afile
```

(with '`/`', not '`\`', as it is interpreted by the Linux git bash)

That is, "the path relative to the root folder of the repo".

Note: the `ProcessInfo` class used by the OP does not support well the '`>`'.
The export of the git command output has to be done programmatically.

Comment: The application still retrieves: "fatal: Path 'D://Test//REPOFOLDER//' exists on disk, but not in 'a2f3f51ee27d5711d2974f0256b4eed0b3225d44'.
" How to solve this issue?

Comment: @Odrai What exact command did you type? What git version are you using (`git --version`)?

Comment: Git version 2.8.1.windows.1 and the command:

"show a2f3f51ee27d5711d2974f0256b4eed0b3225d44:D://Test//MyRepoFolder// > test.cs"

Comment: @Odrai I have edited my answer to illustrate what I meant by "should be the path from the root of the repo" in your case.

Comment: The same error still appears. Maybe we can use TeamViewer?

Comment: Last question/ issue: The command works in Git CMD, but not in my C# application.

**Command:** git show a2f3f51ee27d5711d2974f0256b4eed0b3225d44:test.css > anotherpath\test.css

**Error:** "fatal: ambiguous argument '>': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
"

Comment: @Odrai First, is test.css right under D:\test\ReactiveUI?

Comment: @Odrai Second, can you try and use the --, as requested? `git show a2f3f51ee27d5711d2974f0256b4eed0b3225d44:test.css --`

Comment: I tried 

git show a2f3f51ee27d5711d2974f0256b4eed0b3225d44:ReactiveUI/ExpressionMixins.cs > D:/Downloads/OLDTEST.cs

**AND**

show a2f3f51ee27d5711d2974f0256b4eed0b3225d44:ReactiveUI/ExpressionMixins.cs > --D:/Downloads/OLDTEST.cs

**AND**

show a2f3f51ee27d5711d2974f0256b4eed0b3225d44:ReactiveUI/ExpressionMixins.cs > --D:/Downloads/OLDTEST.cs

Comment: @Odrai the '`--`' is only for the git command, it does not involve whatever is after the `>`. So `git show a2f3f51ee27d5711d2974f0256b4eed0b3225d44:ReactiveUI/ExpressionMixins.cs -- > D:/Downloads/OLDTEST.cs`

Comment: New error: "fatal: D:/Downloads/OLDTEST.cs: 'D:/Downloads/OLDTEST.cs' is outside repository\n"

Comment: @Odrai ok, it consider the rest as part of the git command: not good. `git show a2f3f51ee27d5711d2974f0256b4eed0b3225d44:ReactiveUI/ExpressionMixins.cs > D:/Downloads/OLDTEST.cs` should work, but if it does not, test of the redirection itself is possible: `echo ok > D:/Downloads/OLDTEST.cs` (within your project execution), just to test if that work.

Comment: Can't execute that: "git: 'echo' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.\n\nDid you mean this?\n\tfetch\n"

Comment: @Odrai then `git --version`, for instance

Comment: git --version result is "git version 2.8.1.windows.1\n" within the application.

Comment: @Odrai has it been redirected?

Comment: Apparently my application doesn't support ' > ' that well. So I will use the command without ' > ' and export the content to a destination file. Thanks for helping @VonC

Comment: @Odrai Agreed. I have amended the answer to reflect that.

Comment: At this moment I am using the next command in my application  -C D:\ProjectsFolder\Test2\ReactiveUI log D:/ProjectsFolder/Test2/ReactiveUI/ReactiveUI/Activation.cs, but if e.g. ProjectsFolder contains a space -> "Projects Folder" an error occurs: fatal: Invalid object name 'D'. I already tried -C D:\"Projects Folder"\Test2\Reactive... but the same error appears. Maybe you can point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Odrai Did you try `-C "D:\Projects Folder\Test2\ReactiveUI"`?

Comment: @Odrai what OS, what system are you using? What is the exact command line you are typing?

Comment: @Odrai At this point, it would be best to ask a new question with as much details as possible (and a link back to this one for context)