# Git fetch submodules from latest gitmodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

Suppose I am on commit a which has submodule s1

and somebody added submodule s2 in commit a+1, now I don't want to move to a+1 but fetch(just download) submodule s2.

Is this possible?

my git version is 2.1.4 I can get 2.10.1.windows.1 if required to update

Edit: simple script I tried, it has some problems
   - .git folder is inside the new cloned submodule rather than in super rep's .git/modules folder 
   - working directory is polluted with the new submodule :|

```
git diff HEAD origin/master .gitmodules 2>&1 | perl -e '
while(<>)
{
   if(/^\+\s+path = (.+)/)
   {
      my $path = $1;
      my $line = <>;
      if($line=~/^\+\s+url = (.+)/)
      {
         my $url = $1;
         print "$path -> $url\n";
         `git clone "$url" "$path"`
      }
   }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this possible?

Not exactly: you can [show the content of the latest .gitmodule file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/338470/6309):

```
git fetch
git show origin/master:./.gitmodules
```

That will give you the url of the second submodule s2, but not its SHA1.

If that is enough, you can clone it within your own repo (nested git repo).

---

If you can upgrade to the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (2.11 or soon 2.12), I would use the [`git worktree` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309):

- checkout the `a+1` commit in a separate worktree (with said `git worktree` command), and run a `git submodule update --init` in that separate worktree,
- make (from your own current repo still at commit '`a`') a symbolic link to s2 which is correctly checked out at the right SHA1

That way, you don't move your current repo but still benefit from the actual submodule content `s2` from `a+1`.

Comment: So this is a simple script i made for your 1st method, Is anything wrong here? because when i clone s2 the `.git` folder of submodule is inside the submodule not in the super repository's `.git/modules`
 Edit: putting the script in question as I cant format it here

Comment: @tejas don't bother with the 1st method: it would not know which exact version of s2 to checkout. Do the 2d method with git worktree: it allows you to have multiple working trees, meaning your current working tree will be untouched (except for the symbolic link, which does exist in Windows as well, with a simple junction: `mklink /J`)

Comment: I don't really need to checkout s2, was just trying to save the download time when actually checking out/doing submodule update

Comment: @tejas the download time will be minimal (the git fetch will only download the delta). It is true s2 would be fetched/checked out in full though, unless it is set for a shallow clone. The point is: to get the right s2 content, you need the n+1 commit.

Comment: @tejas Regarding the first method and your script, why not adding the root folder of the nested repo s2 in your .gitignore?