# Viewing previous versions of a file in git (squashed commits)

Tags: git, squash

What I intend to do is similar to what's written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338436/is-there-a-quick-git-command-to-see-an-old-version-of-a-file). I did what the top answer says, however, I realised that I had squashed my commits.

This is what my commit history looks like:

```
Date: <date1>
    commit 3  

Date: <date2>
    commit 2  
    commit 1
```

(I had squashed commit 1 into commit 2.)

As it says in the top answer to the question linked above, I did `git show HEAD~2: file.x` but that shows me the file before commit 1, and doing `git show HEAD~1: file.x` shows me the file after commit 2.

How do I view the file after commit 1 but before commit 2?

Comment: if you committed. it always shows it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the squash happened recently, you could retrieve the original commits 1 and 2 in [the reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) of the relevant branch.

```
git reflog
```

which outputs a list of entries of that form :

```
<commitHash> (optional decoration, as in, branches pointing here) <ref>: <operation>: <details>
```

There you should find your rebase operation in the recent ones. Create a temporary branch just before this point :

```
git checkout -b temp HEAD@{n+1}
```

where `n` is the corresponding ref you spotted.

Now you can freely inspect your pre-squash commits on this temp branch and dispose of it when you're done.

*(Note that all these operations have no impact on your present branches, and you can just dispose of the newly created one when you're done)*